# How to trap on UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, constraints, xcode7

I'm seeing an error appear in my debugger log:

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191f0920 H:[MPKnockoutButton:0x17a876b0]-(34)-[MPDetailSlider:0x17a8bc50](LTR)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

How do I trap on that call? It does not appear anywhere in my code.

[image: Screenshot1]

Comment: In 9 out of 10 cases: this is just caused by: for some view or item on yoru storyboard, you uncheck "Installed".  (For example, just a development button or something you didn't need any more.)  In general, it handles "not-Installed" badly: it often leaves constraints there which become meaningless without the not-Installed item. Often the solution is simply to delete items you have forgotten about, that are sitting around "not-Installed" - just delete 'em.

Answer (score 575, accepted):

This [post](https://nshint.io/blog/2015/08/17/autolayout-breakpoints/) helped me **A LOT**!

I added *UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints* symbolic breakpoint with suggested action:

**Obj-C project**

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

[image: Symbolic breakpoint with custom action in Objective-C project]

**Swift project**

```
expr -l objc++ -O -- [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

[image: Symbolic breakpoint with custom action]

With this hint, the log became more detailed, and It was easier for me identify which view had the constraint broken.

```
UIWindow:0x7f88a8e4a4a0
|   UILayoutContainerView:0x7f88a8f23b70
|   |   UINavigationTransitionView:0x7f88a8ca1970
|   |   |   UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7f88a8f2aab0
|   |   |   |   •UIView:0x7f88a8ca2880
|   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8ca2a10
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f88a8c98820'Archived'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIButtonLabel:0x7f88a8cb0e30'Archived'
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f88a8ca22d0'Download'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIButtonLabel:0x7f88a8cb04e0'Download'
|   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f88a8ca1580'Deleted'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIButtonLabel:0x7f88a8caf100'Deleted'
|   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8ca33e0
|   |   |   |   |   *_UILayoutGuide:0x7f88a8ca35b0
|   |   |   |   |   *_UILayoutGuide:0x7f88a8ca4090
|   |   |   |   |   _UIPageViewControllerContentView:0x7f88a8f1a390
|   |   |   |   |   |   _UIQueuingScrollView:0x7f88aa031c00
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x7f88a8f38070
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x7f88a8f381e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   •UIView:0x7f88a8f39fa0, MISSING HOST CONSTRAINTS
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f88a8cb9bf0'Retrieve data'- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIButton:0x7f88a8cb9bf0'Retrieve data'.minX{id: 170}, UIButton:0x7f88a8cb9bf0'Retrieve data'.minY{id: 171}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f88a8f3ad80- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIImageView:0x7f88a8f3ad80.minX{id: 172}, UIImageView:0x7f88a8f3ad80.minY{id: 173}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *App.RecordInfoView:0x7f88a8cbe530- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for App.RecordInfoView:0x7f88a8cbe530.minX{id: 174}, App.RecordInfoView:0x7f88a8cbe530.minY{id: 175}, App.RecordInfoView:0x7f88a8cbe530.Width{id: 176}, App.RecordInfoView:0x7f88a8cbe530.Height{id: 177}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   +UIView:0x7f88a8cc1d30- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x7f88a8cc1d30.minX{id: 178}, UIView:0x7f88a8cc1d30.minY{id: 179}, UIView:0x7f88a8cc1d30.Width{id: 180}, UIView:0x7f88a8cc1d30.Height{id: 181}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8cc1ec0- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x7f88a8cc1ec0.minX{id: 153}, UIView:0x7f88a8cc1ec0.minY{id: 151}, UIView:0x7f88a8cc1ec0.Width{id: 154}, UIView:0x7f88a8cc1ec0.Height{id: 165}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8e68e10- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x7f88a8e68e10.minX{id: 155}, UIView:0x7f88a8e68e10.minY{id: 150}, UIView:0x7f88a8e68e10.Width{id: 156}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f88a8e65de0- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIImageView:0x7f88a8e65de0.minX{id: 159}, UIImageView:0x7f88a8e65de0.minY{id: 182}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8e69080'8-6-2015'- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UILabel:0x7f88a8e69080'8-6-2015'.minX{id: 183}, UILabel:0x7f88a8e69080'8-6-2015'.minY{id: 184}, UILabel:0x7f88a8e69080'8-6-2015'.Width{id: 185}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8cc0690'16:34'- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UILabel:0x7f88a8cc0690'16:34'.minX{id: 186}, UILabel:0x7f88a8cc0690'16:34'.minY{id: 187}, UILabel:0x7f88a8cc0690'16:34'.Width{id: 188}, UILabel:0x7f88a8cc0690'16:34'.Height{id: 189}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8cc2050- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x7f88a8cc2050.minX{id: 161}, UIView:0x7f88a8cc2050.minY{id: 166}, UIView:0x7f88a8cc2050.Width{id: 163}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f88a8e69d90- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIImageView:0x7f88a8e69d90.minX{id: 190}, UIImageView:0x7f88a8e69d90.minY{id: 191}, UIImageView:0x7f88a8e69d90.Width{id: 192}, UIImageView:0x7f88a8e69d90.Height{id: 193}
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3cc00
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8e618d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f88a8e5ba10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3cd70
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f88a8e58e10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f88a8e5e7a0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3cee0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3dc70
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8e64dd0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8e65290'Average flow rate'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8e712d0'177.0 ml/s'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8c97150'1299.4'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3dde0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8f3df50'Maximum flow rate'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8cbfdb0'371.6 ml/s'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8cc0230'873.5'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3e2a0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8f3e410'Total volume'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8cc0f20'371.6 ml'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3e870
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8f3ea00'Time do max. flow'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8cc0ac0'3.6 s'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3ee10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8f3efa0'Flow time'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8cbf980'2.1 s'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3f3e0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8f3f570'Voiding time'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8cc17e0'3.5 s'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3f9a0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8f3fb30'Voiding delay'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7f88a8cc1380'1.0 s'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8e65000
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f88a8e52f20'Show'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f88a8e6e1d0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f88a8e52c90'Send'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f88a8e61bb0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIButton:0x7f88a8e528e0'Delete'
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIImageView:0x7f88a8e6b3f0
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x7f88a8f3ff60
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *UIActivityIndicatorView:0x7f88a8cba080
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x7f88a8cba700
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UILayoutGuide:0x7f88a8cc3150
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *_UILayoutGuide:0x7f88a8cc3b10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   UIView:0x7f88a8f339c0
|   |   UINavigationBar:0x7f88a8c96810
|   |   |   _UINavigationBarBackground:0x7f88a8e45c00
|   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x7f88a8e46410
|   |   |   UINavigationItemView:0x7f88a8c97520'App'
|   |   |   |   UILabel:0x7f88a8c97cc0'App'
|   |   |   UINavigationButton:0x7f88a8e3e850
|   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x7f88a8e445b0
|   |   |   _UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView:0x7f88a8f2b530

Legend:
    * - is laid out with auto layout
    + - is laid out manually, but is represented in the layout engine because translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES
    • - layout engine host
```

Then I paused execution  [image: Pause]  and I changed problematic view's background color with the command (replacing `0x7f88a8cc2050` with the memory address of *your object* of course)...

**Obj-C**

```
expr ((UIView *)0x7f88a8cc2050).backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
expr -l Swift -- import UIKit
expr -l Swift -- unsafeBitCast(0x7f88a8cc2050, to: UIView.self).backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

... and the result It was awesome!

[image: Hinted View]

Simply amazing!

Comment: @TomCalmon Where did u fire this command to change background color of your view??

Comment: @iAnurag You can run commands in console area, when execution is paused.

Comment: @TomCalmon I did the same...but it shows following error

`rror: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7f88a8cc2050).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`

Comment: It's happening to me the same :/ After all the steps, I write in console: `expr -l Swift -- import UIKit
expr -l Swift -- unsafeBitCast(0x102083e00, to: UITableView.self).backgroundColor = UIColor.red` and I get the same error: `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5214c1438).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.` @iAnurag could you find a solution?

Comment: I get `error: use of undeclared identifier 'expr'` & `error: use of undeclared identifier 'l'`

Comment: @iAnurag this could happen if the view with address=0x7f88a8cc2050 has been already deallocated and not in memory anymore.

Comment: `expr -l objc++ -O -- [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` returns `nil` for me

Comment: Make sure you replace 0x7f88a8cc2050 with the memory address of your object and run the command in the console when execution pauses.

Comment: Still working in Swift 4 and Xcode 9.4, thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfreakingbelievable. Great tip here, totally helped me go straight to the issue. Once the item is changed to red, continue the execution if possible and you'll see the highlight.

Comment: `expr (void)[CATransaction flush]` after changing color

Comment: I also had to check "Automatically continue after evaluating actions" otherwise nothing was dumped into the console.

Comment: @TomHoward any ideas why I don't see any clues in the output: `AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT`, `MISSING HOST CONSTRAINTS`, etc?

Comment: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1001
Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 1.1: "expr -l objc++ -O -- [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]"
Couldn't parse conditional expression:
error: use of undeclared identifier 'expr'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'l'

Comment: How to find the problematic view? I have 30 views... and where to add this line -> Swift -- unsafeBitCast(0x7f88a8cc2050, to: UIView.self).backgroundColor = UIColor.red
Is there a YouTube video for this ?

Comment: When trying this I'm getting `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-5)..`

Comment: Sometimes I get this error when hitting the breakpoint:
`2021-03-24 15:41:42.141413+0100 NB[29965:5238269] *** Assertion failure in -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding], NSISEngine.m:1639
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-5)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`

Comment: For those who get the error ` Error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7f88a8cc2050). The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation ` or smth similar, that is because you are using the example memory address provided in the answer instead of the one found in your project which is causing the issue. You should be replacing the "0x7f88a8cc2050" with the object's memory address which is causing the issue, to find it, look for a "AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT" or a "MISSING HOST CONSTRAINTS" etc in the tree log you receive by using the first command.

Comment: For those who are working in swift 5.0 can execute below command as I was getting `error: <user expression 5>:1:7: use of undeclared identifier 'l'
expr -l Swift -- unsafeBitCast(0x107e6e7f0, to: UIView.self).backgroundColor = UIColor.red`
**So this command worked**
`expr -l objc -- (void)[(UIView *)0x107e6e7f0 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]`

Answer (score 278):

You'll want to add a `Symbolic Breakpoint`.  Apple provides an [excellent guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH8-SW2) on how to do this.

1. Open the Breakpoint Navigator `cmd+7` (`cmd+8` in Xcode 9)
2. Click the `Add` button in the lower left
3. Select `Add Symbolic Breakpoint...`
4. Where it says `Symbol` just type in `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`

You can also treat it like any other breakpoint, turning it on and off, adding actions, or log messages.

Comment: I just don't understand how I can debug the problem better with this hint. I added a symbolic breakpoint but it still doesn't give me enough information whats the problem. The only way is trying to read line by line and understand what causes the problem....otherwise clearing the constraints and again adding them together with the Preview in the asisstent view should help most!

Comment: This might help to get more info after stopping at the breakpoint: http://staxmanade.com/2015/06/debugging-ios-autolayout-issues/

Comment: Just adding that you can now give identifiers to the constraints directly in IB so when you're debugging them, that's the name you'll see.

Comment: (follow-up on @MarqueIV ) `NSLayoutConstraint` has had an `identifier` property since iOS **7** — _Xcode 7 and above_, which can be set both from IB Storyboards as well from code. By setting the identifier you can easier distinguish between system-generated and user-generated constraints in the debug log, e.g. `myConstraint.identifier = "centered image"` (source & examples: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-identifiers-to-debug-autolayout/)

Comment: @AlexCio How it helps? The least it does is it pauses at the moment that it happens. It gives a stack trace where you can backtrack and find the origin...

Comment: @Honey the debug message printed in 2015 was not helpful at all. They've gotten better over the years, and there are better ways of debugging now that allow you to label identifiers with constraints

Comment: It will help you if you have one main view compose from 2-3 child views, you will know where you need to fix the constrains.

Comment: find the memory address in the log when breakpoint stopped and print like: 
po 0x7f9141cdXXX

Answer (score 12):

Followed Stephen's advice and tried to debug the code and whoa! it worked. The answer lies in the debug message itself.

`Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
NSLayoutConstraint:0x191f0920 H:[MPKnockoutButton:0x17a876b0]-(34)-[MPDetailSlider:0x17a8bc50](LTR)>`

The line above tells you that the runtime worked by removing this constraint. May be you don't need Horizontal Spacing on your button (MPKnockoutButton). Once you clear this constraint, it won't complain at runtime & you would get the desired behaviour.

Comment: The compiler?  You mean the runtime?  The compiler didn't remove the constraint. The compiler left it there for the runtime to deal with, hence "recover by breaking constraint" *during runtime*.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I attempt to remove the constraints that the system had to break, my constraints are no longer enough to satisfy the IB (ie "missing constraints" shows in the IB, which means they're incomplete and won't be used). I actually got around this by setting the constraint it wants to break to low priority, which (and this is an assumption) allows the system to break the constraint gracefully. It's probably not the best solution, but it solved my problem and the resulting constraints worked perfectly.

Comment: Typically that is a situation where you want to use a placeholder constraint which is removed at runtime.  To make a constraint a placeholder constraint, go to the constraint inspector and click "Remove at build time".  Notice how the constraint I-beam symbol in the IB drawing area turns from blue to grey to indicate this.

Comment: I had the same issue. when i remove the broken constraint my design broke. So i set the priority to medium.

Answer (score 0):

This usually appears when you want to use `UIActivityViewController` in iPad.

Add below, before you present the controller to mark the arrow.

`activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = senderView.frame // senderView can be your button/view you tapped to call this VC`

I assume you already have below, if not, add together:

`activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem I have is when I see something like this:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002faf7a0 'UISV-alignment' UIStackView:0x7fcdda716770.top == UIStackView:0x7fcdda7291d0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002f84dc0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000035a8620'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.top == UILabel:0x7fcdda716900.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002f8dfe0 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIImageView:0x7fcdda7170c0]-(2)-[UIStackView:0x7fcdda7291d0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002f84e60 'UISV-spacing' V:[UILabel:0x7fcdda716900]-(2)-[UIImageView:0x7fcdda7170c0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002f84c80 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(20)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000035a8620'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fcdda716770 )>"
)
```

I assume, ew.  They don't really expect me to deal with this garbage... But maybe that is all we get and maybe it isn't so bad.

Lets break it somewhat down, the codes refer to ids of constraints.  You can actually find out which constraint they correspond to by simply printing out your constraints like so:

```
print("my Constraint", ibOutletConstraint)
```

You'll get:

```
my Constraint Optional(<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001625a90 UIStackView:0x7fdca0c0d1f0.width == 2*UIStackView: 0x7fcdda716770.width   (inactive)>)
```

Now I can grab: `0x7fcdda716770` and search my output to match it to the constraint in question.  Its tedious and certainly not glamorous, but it is a way to step by step break it down.  I think Apple should really make it clearer which constraint is having an issue.